# How to get percentage value of each column across all rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

Using R's tidyverse, how do I get the **percentage** value of each column across rows? Using the mpg dataset as an example, I've tried the following code:

```
new_mpg <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>%
    summarise (n = n()) %>% 
      spread(model, n) %>% 
        mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric)

new_mpg[,-1] %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(.))
```

I'm looking to create the following output:

```
manufacturer | 4runner4wd |     a4    | a4 quattro | a6 quattro | altima |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
audi         |     NA     | 0.3888889 |   0.444444 | 0.166667   |   NA   |
```

However, when I get to

```
new_mpg[,-1] %>% 
      mutate(sum = rowSums(.))
```

the sum column returns NA. And I'm unable to calculate the n()/sum. I will just get NA. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Add `na.rm = TRUE` in your sum. Many aggregation functions like `sum`, `mean`, etc default to `NA` if any value is `NA` as a failsafe

Comment: But also, keep in mind that making columns out of all the models means that you're going to have a ton of columns that don't apply to your rows. If all you want is proportions within groups, there are better ways to do it, either keeping the data in a long shape, or splitting by manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @camille mentioned in the comments you need an `na.rm = TRUE` in the `rowSums` call. To get the percentage of each model in the manufacturer you need to first count the number of each model grouped by manufacturer and model and then get the percentage grouped only by manufacturer. `dplyr` is smart in this way because it removes one layer of grouping after the `summarise` so you just need to add a mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
new_mpg <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, model) %>%
  summarise (n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  spread(model, n) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric)

new_mpg[,-1] %>% 
  mutate(sum = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))
```